# Jquery validation with Data Annotations in MVC3 without use of Unobstrusive

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a class:

```
public class EditableOrder
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Order ID is required.")]
    public int OrderID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Customer ID must be 5 characters.")]
    public string CustomerID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

}

I want get validation attributes `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Order ID is required.")]` defined in the above class in jQuery.

For jQuery validation i need to add class to input element to validate input.
but i cant able to get `[Required]` attribute in jQuery.

Note: without using unobtrusive

Comment: What did you mean by *"without using unobtrusive"* ?

Answer (score 0):

Data annotations emit HTML5 data-* attributes on the corresponding input fields that you could access:

```
var requiredMessage = $('#OrderID').data('val-required');
```